# Exception when starting up the eclipse platform for a junit test

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, junit, mockito

I have the following situation:

- A class A which make some initializations in a static block.
- A class B which needs the first class, A.

Class A is not under my control, it comes from a library and I can't replace the library or the class A.
When I want to write a unit test for B class and I'm trying to mock the A class, the static block from A class is executed and I get:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedSerializationConstructorAccessor1.newInstance(Unknown Source)
...
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.runtime.AssertionFailedException: assertion failed: The application has not been initialized.
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.InternalPlatform.assertInitialized(InternalPlatform.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.InternalPlatform.getAdapterManager(InternalPlatform.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.getAdapterManager(Platform.java:595)
    at test.A.<clinit>(A.java:12)
    ... 43 more
```

Here are the class A, B and the test:

#### A.java

```java
package test;

import org.eclipse.core.runtime.IAdapterManager;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform;

public class A {

    static {
        IAdapterManager adapterManager = Platform.getAdapterManager();
    }

    public A() {
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        //
    }
}
```

#### B.java

```java
package test;

public class B {

    private A a;

    public B(A a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public B() {
    }

    public void someMethod() {
        a.doSomething();
    }

    public void setA(A a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
}
```

#### TestB.java

```java
package test;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.Mockito;

public class TestB {

    private B b;
    private A a;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        a = Mockito.mock(A.class);
        b = new B(a);
    }

    @Test
    public void testSomeMethod() throws Exception {
        //
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        //
    }
}
```

So, the question would be, what should I do in the unit test to initialize the eclipse platform before the "Mockito.mock(A.class);"?

The problem is that when "Platform.getAdapterManager()" is called, "InternalPlatform.getDefault().getAdapterManager()" is called and then "assertInitialized()" is called, which will throw "java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError" with

> Caused by: org.eclipse.core.runtime.AssertionFailedException:
>   assertion failed: The application has not been initialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try [PowerMock](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/) which supports the removal of static initializers. See [here](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/SuppressUnwantedBehavior) for an example.

In summary, you annotate your test class with `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)` and `@SuppressStaticInitializationFor("org.mycompany.ClassWithStaticInitializer")`.